# Equivalent axiomatizations of $\mathbf{S4}$

Tags: logic, reference-request, modal-logic

The standard axiomatization of the modal logic $\mathbf{S4}$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
  &\Box(\varphi\rightarrow\psi)\rightarrow(\Box\varphi \rightarrow\Box\psi) \\
  &\Box\varphi \rightarrow\Box\Box\varphi\\
  &\Box\varphi \rightarrow\varphi
 \end{split}
\qquad
          \begin{split}
                &\bf{(K)}\\
                &\bf{(4)}\\
                &\bf{(T)}
            \end{split}
\end{equation*}
with rules of inference

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
 \{\varphi,\varphi\rightarrow\psi\}&\vdash \psi\\
  \{\varphi\}&\vdash \Box\varphi
 \end{split}
\qquad
          \begin{split}
                &\bf{(MP)}\\
                &\bf{(N)}\\
            \end{split}
\end{equation*}
for any well formed $\varphi,\psi$.
In working on a project, I came across another axiomatization which states $\mathbf{S4}$ is equivalent to

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&\Box \top \\
&\Box(\varphi\wedge \psi) \leftrightarrow \Box \varphi \wedge \Box \psi\\
&\Box\varphi \rightarrow\Box\Box\varphi\\
&\Box\varphi \rightarrow\varphi
\end{split}
\qquad
\begin{split}
&\bf{(N)}\\
&\bf{(R)}\\
&\bf{(4)}\\
&\bf{(T)}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
with rules of inference
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
 \{\varphi,\varphi\rightarrow\psi\}&\vdash \psi\\
  \{\varphi\rightarrow\psi\}&\vdash \Box\varphi\rightarrow\Box\psi
 \end{split}
\qquad
          \begin{split}
                &\bf{(MP)}\\
                &\bf{(M)}\\
            \end{split}
\end{equation*}
for any well formed $\varphi,\psi.$

However, I can't find any reference to this axiomatization in any of the classic modal logic text (Chellas, Cresswell & Hughes, Blackburn et al.).

Does anyone know of any references as to why these are equivalent, or proofs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three initial points:

First, the rules are crucially mis-stated. The necessitation rule **N** is not $$\{\varphi\} 
\vdash \Box\varphi$$
but rather
$$\textrm{if } \vdash\varphi \textrm{ then  }\vdash \Box\varphi,$$
and similarly for **M**. Getting this right will help!

Second reflect that $\varphi$ is provably equivalent to $(\top \to \varphi)$, and we see why **M** gives the rule **N**; while **N** plus **K** obviously gives **M**.

Third, it is a routine exercise to prove **R** in the first version of S4. So all that remains to show that these systems really are equivalent is to prove **K** in the second system ... (easier said than done?).